# TouchableHighlight: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I already know that `<TouchableHighlight>` can have specifically 1 child, but when I do that, I STILL get the error: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

What is going on? Is it a bug?

I literally took this example from somewhere online and it is supposed to work:

```
            <View>
              <Text>Tony Stark is Ironman</Text>
              <TouchableHighlight>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: "50px",
                    height: "50px",
                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
```

Yet, I still get the error.

This is the entire code:

```
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <Button title={props.title} onPress={toggleModal} color="#006600" />
        <Modal
          isVisible={isModalVisible}
          backdropColor="white"
          style={{ marginTop: 55 }}
        >
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              borderBottomColor: "#000000",
              borderBottomWidth: 2,
              padding: 15,
            }}
          >
            <Button title="Cancel" onPress={toggleModal} color="red" />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Name of park/launch"
              multiline
              style={{ height: 60, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
              onChangeText={(t) => setName(t)}
              value={name}
            />
            <View>
              <Text>Tony Stark is Ironman</Text>
              <TouchableHighlight>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: "50px",
                    height: "50px",
                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            {/* <TextInput
              placeholder="Comments"
              multiline
              style={{ height: 60, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
              onChangeText={(t) => setComments(t)}
              value={comments}
            /> */}
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Tags (separate each tag by a comma)"
              multiline
              style={{ height: 60, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
              onChangeText={(t) => setTags(t)}
              value={tags}
            />
            <Text>Rate the difficulty of this location</Text>
            <Slider
              step={1}
              minimumValue={0}
              maximumValue={10}
              value={difficulty}
              onValueChange={(slideValue) => setDifficultyValue(slideValue)}
              minimumTrackTintColor="#1fb28a"
              maximumTrackTintColor="#d3d3d3"
              thumbTintColor="#b9e4c9"
            />
            <Text>Difficulty value: {difficulty}</Text>
            <ImagePickerExample></ImagePickerExample>
            <Button
              raised
              icon={{ name: "check" }}
              title="Submit"
              name="submit"
              color="green"
              onPress={onSubmit}
            />
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </Modal>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for whitespaces or something like that inside `<TouchableHighlight />`

Comment: I just looked and not seeing any issues